# Bootstrap collapsed menu toggle doesn't un-focus when clicked a second time

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, focus, navbar

In a collapsed mode, when I click the navbar toggle menu button, the menu drops down and the toggle button is focused. When I click the button again, the menu is retracted back up, but the toggle menu button doesnt get un-focused unless I click someother area on the screen.

This is the relevant CSS code I used for the navbar toggle:

```
.navbar-default>.container .navbar-toggle{
  border-color: #49B0A8;
}

.navbar-default>.container .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default>.container .navbar-toggle:focus{
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>$(".navbar-toggle").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).blur();
})</script>
```

This removes the focus from the button after your mouse lets go.